# Ввод символа с клавиатуры

Tags: консоль, c++

Надо, чтобы программа в цикле запрашивала ввести значение до тех пор, пока не будет введено q. Когда будет введено q, программа должна закрыться.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int _tmain()
{    
    int ch = 0;

    while (ch != 'q') {
        ch = _getch();
        ch = toupper(ch);
    }
}
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: Кавычки должны быть одинарными.

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов, ок всё равно не работает

Comment: [В чем ошибка?](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/09/blog-post_24.html)

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать? И что именно не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    char str=0;//тут должна быть хоть какаята инициализация, 
               //иначе может ругаться на то что: "while (str != 'q')" str-неизвестен

    while (str != 'q'){//тут должны быть одинарные кавычки, 
                       //или может ругаться на const char
        str=getchar(); 
    }
```

а вообще зачем  так напрягаться? cin>>str; непроще ли? (вроде как тег C++, нахрена использовать C ?)

---

добавлено 12.11.2012

так как автор переделал свой вопрос то теперь правильный ответ у [[@Rules](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)

Answer (score 1):

Я даже не знаю C/C++ но подозреваю что `toupper(ch)` возвращает `ch` в верхнем регистре, и даже если пользователь введёт `'q'`, неужели вы думаете что `'Q' == 'q'`.

Comment: Да, в данном случае основная ошибка это toupper() вместо tolower().

Comment: @rules, спасибо за комплимент. Я же учусь. Два года кодил на делфи теперь переучиваюсь

Comment: Извините, @ололо но мне кажется что такие ошибки находятся элементарным *переводом имени ф-ции на русский* :)